# Json Parsing in Php Foreach

Tags: php, json

I have one json data but i can't parsing because first type is not have name.

```
    [
{"id":325,"distance":239,"text":"test","position":{"lat":2,"lon":3}},
{"id":333,"distance":123,"text":"test","position":{"lat":2,"lon":3}},
{"id":331,"distance":1,"text":"test","position":{"lat":2,"lon":3}}
    ]
```

Php code

```
$jsonurl = "url address";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);

$obj = json_decode($json,true);

$it = "<ul>"
    foreach ($obj[0] as $list) 
    {
        $it .= "<h4>".$list['id']."</h4>"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `stdClass Object` not an `array`, so access it like this,

```
$it .= "<h4>".$list->id."</h4>";
```

And also change your for loop like this

```
foreach ($obj as $list) 
            ^ remove [0] here
```

Finally your loop looks like this,

```
foreach ($obj as $list) 
{
    $it .= "<h4>".$list->id."</h4>"
}
```

see [demo here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ccdb5d4efdad76b00c61061ea5922ae143ff30b3)

Comment: if you `print_r($obj)`, what you are getting. Do this before for loop.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 325 [distance] => 239 [text] => test [position] => Array ( [lat] => 2 [lon] => 3 ) ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 333 [distance] => 123 [text] => test [position] => Array ( [lat] => 2 [lon] => 3 ) ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 331 [distance] => 1 [text] => test [position] => Array ( [lat] => 2 [lon] => 3 ) ) )

Comment: @ZgrKARALAR did u check the demo?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping it work when i delete true in json_decode.

Comment: consider accepting  the answer, Glad it helped you:)

Comment: But what about if i want to list position":{"lat":2,"lon":3}} not working with list-> lat :)

Comment: inside loop, `$list->position->lat;` and `$list->position->lon;`